# Django import excel file returns blank even if there is data in my excel file?

Tags: django

I'm new to django and i really want to learn this  framework. I tried to implement django-import-export in my project. I followed the django-import-export documentation and I encountered a problem when importing excel file.

Here is my Status Model

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Status(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Status'
    StatusCode = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.StatusCode
```

Here is the excel content

[Status.xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6g1e.png)

Here is the preview when i import the excel file
[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RD6Sf.png)

Why is it that the output is blank?

Comment: As a convention, you should put the `Meta` class after all your fields. Also, I see four rows in your view, which matches your excel file. Mind also posting your view?

Comment: Sir I did not yet put any code on my view. The preview was a superuser account in django admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're having this issue cos you don't have a **status** field in your models.py file. Try changing StatusCode to status and also ensure that each heading of data in each column on your .xlsx file matches a field in the model file.

N.B. Also note that the fields in your models file and the heading of the .xlsx file must be in the same case e.g using snake case in your models and also using snake case in your .xlsx file

## Create your models here.

```
class Status(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Status'
    Status = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Status
```